# How do I upload swagger-ui to a server on the Internet?

Tags: c#, swagger

I created the swagger API in C#, was able to put the site on React using the netlife service. Now I want my API to work not only if I run it, but so that it is on a remote server, but I don't know how to do it. Please describe in detail how I can do this (preferably free hosting or with a small fee)

Comment: Swagger is integrated into your application's middleware pipeline. You don't need to do anything different to deploy. It is automatically deployed as part of your application.

Comment: I run the react website separately and through visual studio swagger

Comment: are you asking about hosting your API itself ?